# Rails, radio button not storing value in boolean field on DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I  have created a small form to allow users submit 'opinions'. This can be positive or negative.
I got a 'positive' boolean field on the DB. This should be true if positive or false if negative.

```
=form_for @opinion do |f|
        = f.hidden_field :event_id
        %p
          =f.radio_button(:positive, :checked => (:positive == 1))
          =f.label :true, 'Positive'
          =f.radio_button(:positive, :checked => (:positive == 0))
          =f.label :false, 'Negative'
        %p
          =f.label 'Body'
          =f.text_area :body
        =f.submit
```

However, everything is stored right but the positive field. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I get

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EgFB9zohTA93ClNAQpS0qcsEivSCe1imjDUuw/e/YYA=", "opinion"=>{"event_id"=>"31", "positive"=>"{:checked=>false}", "body"=>"asdasasdasd"}, "commit"=>"Create Opinion", "locale"=>"en"}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a simple checkbox? if checked than positive, if not then negative. or whatever

Comment: I prefer a visual of 2 options for the users to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will add 'checked' when your attribute's value is equal to the supplied value

```
=f.radio_button :positive, 1
=f.label :true, 'Positive'
=f.radio_button :positive, 0
=f.label :false, 'Negative'
```

please check the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:checked` stuff. If your database field is a boolean, than rails form_for knows which f.radio_button to check.